Cannot Import keras-vggface in Colab with Tensorflow2.x
I was supposed to "import keras_vggface", and it give the following report: Since Tensorflow upgrade to 2.x, there are a lot problem to import keras-vggface. Anyone knows how to fix it?
%tensorflow_version 2.x
!pip install keras-applications keras-preprocessing
!pip install keras-vggface
!pip install scikit-image
!pip install pydot
import keras_vggface




ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
\<ipython-input-2-7a523c30fa3e\> in \<cell line: 1\>()
\----\> 1 import keras_vggface
2 print(keras_vggface.__file__)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_vggface/models.py in \<module\>
14     AveragePooling2D, Reshape, Permute, multiply
15 from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import \_obtain_input_shape
\---\> 16 from keras.utils import layer_utils
17 from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
18 from keras import backend as K

ImportError: cannot import name 'layer_utils' from 'keras.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/api/utils/__init__.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.


I need to successfully import keras-vggface in Cloab, with Tensorflow2.x

layer_utils is no longer supported by keras in new versions. I think you should try installing tensorflow and keras to older version when it's still supported (tensorflow==2.13.0 and keras==2.12)
pip install --force-reinstall tensorflow==2.13.0
pip install --force-reinstall keras==2.12

